# How can I verify the authenticity of requests from a php app to my web service?

Tags: php, web-services, authentication

I'd like to accept requests from a php app to my web service. How can I verify that requests made to the web service come from the php app (or indeed any authorised source) and are not forged?

My web service relies on the received requests being from allowed domain(s) and not from some bot that's sending data and portending to be from that domain.

Comment: if your needs are not complex, a simple pre-shared key would be enough. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-shared_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I verify that requests made to the web service come from the
>   php app (or indeed any authorised source) and are not forged?

Well, verify their identity and reject when its wrong or missing.

> My web service relies on the received requests being from allowed
>   domain(s) and not from some bot

Actually, what you're thinking here is checking the HTTP referrer. This happens to be one of those fields that is easily spoofed. so you shouldn't really rely on that to be the ultimate test of validity. instead, I'd do the following:

start by googling / researching these topics:

- HTTP requests, specifically passing data in headers
- generating auth tokens
- storing auth tokens in cookies

So, basically, a lot of the time you'll read about APIs that work this way, essentially:
a client does an initial authentication API method somehow, which will generate a temporary auth token (which follows a format usually, ie md5(userID+timestamp+authlevel+etc+etc) ). Then you include your auth token in the header in all of the subsequent requests that are made to other API methods. then your API first validates that token, and if it is valid, it executes the method

for tutorials / info about good API development, you should go check out [APIGEE](http://apigee.com/about/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I've updated my question slightly to better explain the problem.

Comment: my answer applies still. you must make the client at least verify it is who you think it is, and then give them a token to keep. have them pass the token with every request. and if its missing or incorrect, then you have a reason to block the request (regardless of whether or not its from a *bot*) lol

Comment: How can the website verify itself without usernames and passwords?

Comment: it doesn't have to be a token based on a user and password. you can use other stuff... an IP maybe. haha sky is the limit man!

Comment: but IP address and everything else can be spoofed couldn't they?

Comment: please see my answer above, think it over, and think creatively. you'll come up with something

Comment: Ok, here is a better definition. Let's say if my web service needs to know how many times my WordPress plugin is used, I can't know know anything about the WordPress installation that can help me authenticate it. Nor I know if what's sent to me is from my Plugin instead of some cURL post. Do you think your answer still stands?